# PHP Project relative paths and urls

Tags: php, relative-path

I'm working on a project. It's a control panel to manage a website.
The folder structure is like this:

- Root

  - images
  - css
  - js
  - modules

    - users
    - categories
    - etc..
  - index.php
  - config.php

I set some settings in my config file, some of those are:

```
$site_url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
define ('ABSPATH', 'http://'.$site_url.'/cpanel');
```

So, my question is: How can I load all resources (images, css, js) relative to the `ABSPATH` constant, and all `<a>` tags?

With this, I could move the "cpanel project" to an other directory level and it would still work. Like a Wordpress Blog, only setting the Blog URL..

Comment: Sorry for offtopic, but maybe you need something bigger than pure php? Maybe switch to some framework? CodeIgniter is simplest, easiest to use and I saved a lot of my time by using it.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't you just do something like this in your php view?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= ABSPATH ?>/my_js_file.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= ABSPATH ?>/my_css_file.css">

<img src="<?= ABSPATH ?>/my_image_file.jpg" />
```

This way, you could move the directory anywhere within your docroot and just change the value of `ABSPATH` in your config file.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably best served defining several different variables, as having a URL is not going to be useful for purposes of includes and such.  You can do something like this:

```
DEFINE(HOST_NAME, $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
DEFINE(WEB_SERVER_ROOT, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
DEFINE(APP_ROOT, __DIR__);
DEFINE(URI_BASE, str_replace(WEB_SERVER_ROOT, '', APP_ROOT);
if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') {
    DEFINE(PROTOCOL, 'http');
} else {
    DEFINE(PROTOCOL, 'https');
}
DEFINE(URL_BASE, PROTOCOL . '://' . URI_BASE);
```

For includes you could then do something like:

```
include(APP_ROOT . '/modules/somefile.php');
```

For outputting image, javascript, css, etc. links you could use something like:

```
<img src="<?php echo URL_BASE; ?>/images/someimage.jpg" />
<a href="<?php echo URL_BASE; ?>/somepage">Some Page</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo URL_BASE; ?>/js/somejs.js" />
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, but i will be to change o create either img and anchors with this constant?

Comment: @mauriblint I have added examples for using the constant within links or to reference javascript in my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do what you are saying, but one of the most simple one is to use the BASE tag.

```
<head>
<base href="http://www.yoursitewithimages.com/folder-with-files/" target="_blank">
</head>
```

Then you can just use

```
<img src="img/image.jpg">
```

and it will be read as

```
<img src="http://www.yoursitewithimages.com/folder-with-files/img/image.jpg">
```

More info here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp or here http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/base.html

Comment: w3schools has been known as a very bad resource for a while, [w3.org](http://w3.org) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/base) are much better resources.

Comment: @dualed thanks for the comment dualed, I have updated my info link.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative based on Mike Brant's solution.

```
//APP_ROOT and APP_BASE assumes that the current location of this 
//script is located in the root of your application.  
//Also assumes that the HOST_NAME is what you want in the URL.  
//See https://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php for reference 
define('HOST_NAME', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? define('PROTOCOL', 'http') : define('PROTOCOL', 'https');
define('WEB_SERVER_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define('APP_ROOT', __DIR__);
$appBase = str_replace(pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
define('URL_BASE', PROTOCOL . '://' . HOST_NAME . $appBase);
```